# How to add a property bag to a Site/List?

Tags: sharepoint

This might be bit non programming related but thought to add it here.

I am working on a code that retrieves the Property bags from the Sharepoint server. Now I need to test it. In order to do that I need to associate some custom properties with sharepoint objects. (i.e Add property bags)

How can I do that manually in sharepoint. Honestly I prefer to do it manually not using a code. Using a code for it may raise some unnecessary complexities.

Any help/link would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a website's property bag via SharePoint Designer. Open the website with SharePoint Designer, then open the "Site" menu and chose "Site settings ...". There you'll find a "Parameters" tab showing the website's property bag.

Answer (score 1):

CodePlex has a solution for settings up Property Bags. Try this link, i have tried this. All you need to do is set the property through the central admin. you can target any of the web application in the farm. Pretty neat ;-)

http://www.codeplex.com/pbs

let me know how it went :-)